# How to export python output from terminal (function code)?

Tags: python

I have a piece of code where I am trying to export the output. I tried this, but the only problem was where and what ~str~ had to be.

```
with open("piStorage.txt", "w") as fp:
    fp.write(~str~)
```

Here is my code to find ~str~

```
import csv
import time
start_time = time.time()

def calcPi(limit):
    q, r, t, k, n, l = 1, 0, 1, 1, 3, 3
    decimal = limit
    counter = 0
    while counter != decimal + 1:
            if 4 * q + r - t < n * t:
                    yield n
                    if counter == 0:
                            yield '.'
                    if decimal == counter:
                            print('')
                            break
                    counter += 1
                    nr = 10 * (r - n * t)
                    n = ((10 * (3 * q + r)) // t) - 10 * n
                    q *= 10
                    r = nr
            else:
                    nr = (2 * q + r) * l
                    nn = (q * (7 * k) + 2 + (r * l)) // (t * l)
                    q *= k
                    t *= l
                    l += 2
                    k += 1
                    n = nn
                    r = nr
def main():
    pi_digits = calcPi(int(input(
        "Enter the number of decimals to calculate to: ")))
    i = 0
    for d in pi_digits:
            print(d, end='')
            i += 1
            if i == 200:
                print("")
                i = 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

with open("piStorage.txt", "w") as fp:
    fp.write(main)
```

I tried using this, but it doesn't work. It came up as:
"

Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "c:\Users\William\Desktop\pi.py", line 48, in <module> 
fp.write(main) 
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not function

"

```
with open("piStorage.txt", "w") as fp:
    fp.write(main)
```

Comment: I'm not clear as to what you want...`fp.write(main)` seems like you are just hoping random values work. `stdout` is likely what you're after

Answer (score 1):

You can use `contextlib.redirect_stdout`.

```py
def main():
    pi_digits = calcPi(int(input(
        "Enter the number of decimals to calculate to: ")))
    i = 0
    from contextlib import redirect_stdout
    with open("piStorage.txt", "w") as fp:
        with redirect_stdout(fp):
            for d in pi_digits:
                    print(d, end='')
                    i += 1
                    if i == 200:
                        print("")
                        i = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fp.write(main)
```

Since you're using a function name without parentheses `()`, this refers to the *function object* itself.

I think you meant to *call* the function by using parentheses:

```
fp.write(main())
```

This will call `main()` and write its returned value to the file.

However in this case that still won't work, because the way you've written `main()`, it doesn't actually *return* anything.

You need to change `main()` so that it writes to the file directly, instead of calling `print()`.